# Android: Activity restarts on switch to landscape/keyboard flips out

Tags: android, keyboard, android-activity, landscape, portrait

When a user flips their keyboard out or switches between portrait and landscape, the activity seemingly restarts. This is fine except I have my activity play music. When this occurs, there are then TWO music files playing, and pressing back only stops ONE of them! I've disabled switching between portrait and landscape for the activity, but sliding the keyboard out still causes the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrstly, check out the [android:configurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) attribute. Secondly, the music playing is usually done by the service or the AsyncTask in simple cases. Try this two approaches.

Comment: Agree with the latter (music playback handled by a service). Google recommends avoiding the former (`android:configurationChanged`) wherever possible.